# Variable declarations and datatypes

Tags: c, variables, global-variables, local-variables, variable-declaration

In the following statements first three are definitions and the last one is the declaration:

```
auto int i;

static int j;

register int k;

extern int l;
```

What's the reason for the same?

Comment: The last one tells the compiler that `int l` is defined somewhere else, and the linker will find it.

Comment: Is the question actually about what is the difference between *definition* and *declaration*?

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes

Comment: Similarly with functions: the **declaration** (prototype) informs the compiler about the form of the function, and the **definition** implements the code.

Answer (score 1):

In first three(**int i, static int j, register int k**) is a definition. It denotes the space for the integer to be in this translation unit and advices the linker to link all references to i against this entity. If you have more or less than exactly one of these definitions, the linker will complain.

But in last **extern int l**, is a declaration, since it just introduces/specifies l,  no new memory address/space is allocated. You can have as many extern int l in each compilation unit as you want.
A **declaration** introduces names into a translation unit or redeclares names introduced by previous declarations.

Comment: Exactly once... it is quite legal to define a(n uninitialised) variable at global scope twice, such as `int i; int i;`

Comment: In C, int i; in the file scope (outside any function) is a declaration and a tentative definition. Multiple tentative definitions are allowed; only one definition is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is about the terms *declaration*  and *definition* in C.

- A *declaration* tells the compiler name and type of "*something*".
- A *definition* is a declaration, but additionally "creates" the "*something*" that is declared. E.g. for a variable, this would introduce some storage space for this variable.

In your first three examples, the variables are actually created. The storage classes `auto`, `static` and `register` all just specify a storage duration. In contrast, the storage class `extern` tells the compiler that this variable is *known*, but it might exist in a different *translation unit*.

Maybe an example comparing the *declaration* and *definition* of functions will make the concept easier to understand:

```
// function declaration:
int foo(int x);
// (now we know a function foo should be "somewhere", but it doesn't exist yet)

// function definition:
int foo(int x) {
    return x+1;
}
```